# Retrieving a select drop down value with a space in between the value string php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, default-value

At the moment I have a working select drop down which has an on-change event to manipulate the data within a certain div.

It works just as I want but I am having trouble retrieving a value which has a space in between to return anything. I know and I have checked that the value is storing the correct data to the database but it's simply not working.

I have also searched online and everything seems to be all good with my code but this is strange.

My question: How do I retrieve a select dropdown value attribute from the database which has a space in between the string of text?

Below is my code:

header.php

```
<select id="category" class="selectDropDown">
                    <option>Select Category...</option>
                    <option value="All Categories">All Categories</option>
                    <option value="Financial">Financial</option>
                    <option value="Administration">Business And Administration</option>
                    <option value="Care">Care</option>
                    <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
                    <option value="Creative">Creative</option>
```

and so on. The problem is with the all categories value.

```
category.php

include('config.php');

$category = $_REQUEST['category'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM podContent WHERE category = '$category'";

$result = mysql_query( $query, $con );
```

Any help is much appreciated, this may be a simple solution but I've just been looking at it for hours now. Cheers

Comment: Your PHP script is open to SQL injection, I suggest you read up on that first and foremost. It is advised you use PDO these days as well: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I know I should be using PDO but at the moment I am looking for a more straight forward security option, anything you suggest opposed to PDO?

Comment: The alternatives are prone to developer error (forgetting to escape query strings).

Comment: Sorry to both you but in terms of implementing the PDO solution, would it be easy enough to configure in say 1 to 2 days?

Comment: Should take no more than 5 mins to install and enable in PHP if it's not already there. Then you just need to update your scripts wherever you call `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Agree @diggersworld +1

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `name` attribute of the `select`, not the `id` attribute. In your case, you should change the HTML to

```
<select id="category" name="category" class="selectDropDown">
    ...
</select>
```